# Output data does not match headers, off by one

Tags: python

I have vaccination text data like this:

```
vaccinations_text = """
|Entry #|Vaccine|Type of vaccine|Lot #|Manufacturer|VIS edition date|Date given|Vaccinator (initials)|
|1|Influenza|H1N1|2F03930|NOV|8/24/09|12/7/09|PLE|
|2|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Td|U049393AA|ASP|4/2/95|10/7/95|ODK|
|3|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Td|U049393AA|ASP|4/2/95|11/7/95|WMK|
|4|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Td|U049393AA|ASP|4/2/95|4/7/96|CPK|
|5|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Tdap|AC9349239AA|GSK|2/12/07|3/1/07|CPK|
|6|Measles, Mumps, Rubella|MMR|02302L|DVX|9/7/15|11/4/15|WNK|
|7|Hepatitis B|Heplisav-B|TD02302|DVX|9/9/16|10/4/18|WNK|
"""
```

Now, what I want to do is parsing the fictitious vaccination information from the vaccinations_text string to create a list of lists describing the vaccination information of each entry from the table.

Specifically, I want to create a list named vaccination_records where each element of the list is a vaccine record corresponding to a line of text from the original string. Each vaccine record should be modeled as a list of tuples, where each tuple is comprised of the column header and the value in that column.

For example, Entry 1 should be parsed into: [('Entry #', 1), ('Vaccine', 'Influenza'), ('Type of vaccine', 'H1N1'), ...], and so on. Represent all dates using the dt.date class.

I wrote the code like this:

```
vaccination_records = []
lines = vaccinations_text.strip().split('\n')
headers = lines[0].split('|')[1:-1]  
date_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2})')

for line in lines[1:]:
    values = line.split('|')[1:-1]  
    record = [('Entry #', int(values[0]))]

    for header, value in zip(headers, values[1:]):
        if header == 'Date given':
            date = date_pattern.search(value)
            if date:
                date = dt.datetime.strptime(date.group(0), '%m/%d/%y').date()
                record.append((header, date))
        else:
            record.append((header, value))

    vaccination_records.append(record)
```

But when I test whether I parse right or not, I use this code:

```
for record in vaccination_records:
    for item in record:
        if item[0] == 'Entry #':
            if item[1] == 1:
                print("Entry 1 has been successfully parsed:")
                print(record)
                break
```

and then it looks like the output is not exactly what I expected. the output looks like this:

```
Entry 1 has been successfully parsed:
[('Entry #', 1), ('Entry #', 'Influenza'), ('Vaccine', 'H1N1'), ('Type of vaccine', '2F03930'), ('Lot #', 'NOV'), ('Manufacturer', '8/24/09'), ('VIS edition date', '12/7/09')]
```

So my question is that how can I revise the code to get the desired output like:

```
[('Entry #', 1), ('Vaccine', 'Influenza'), ('Type of vaccine', 'H1N1'), ...]
```

Comment: Your title should be about a specific technical issue that prevents you from completing your program itself; instead of describing what your program is for, describe _the specific issue that stopped you from finishing the program yourself_ in such a way that someone can tell if they have the same problem (and are likely to be helped by the solutions you received) even if they're writing a program that has nothing to do with vaccination records.

Comment: That said -- you're starting `header` from the default `[0:]`, which is where you're getting the extra `Entry #` from. Because you're injecting the `[('Entry #', int(values[0]))]` starting record, you should start `headers` from `[1:]` just the same as you start `values` from `[1:]` to keep your items paired and avoid the duplicate.

Comment: This question is reproducible with the code, and not due to a typo - it may well be a duplicate of another question somewhere, but then it's been closed for the wrong reasons. I think my answer as well as the added "batteries included" solution by VonWoodSon provide sufficient value as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select these headers:

```
headers = lines[0].split('|')[1:-1]
```

So, that's skipping the first header (at position 0) and including the rest, except the last. However, the header being skipped is empty, since the headers line starts with a `|`. So, `headers` is still `['Entry #', 'Vaccine', ...]`

You then initialise `record` with the first value:

```
record = [('Entry #', int(values[0]))]
```

And proceed to add all other values, paired with headers:

```
for header, value in zip(headers, values[1:]):
```

This matches `'Entry #'` (the first header) with `'Influenza'` (the second value), etc.  And that's exactly the result you get.

Instead:

```
record = []

# and
for header, value in zip(headers, values):
```

Gets you what you need. The adjusted source:

```
import re
import datetime as dt

vaccinations_text = """
|Entry #|Vaccine|Type of vaccine|Lot #|Manufacturer|VIS edition date|Date given|Vaccinator (initials)|
|1|Influenza|H1N1|2F03930|NOV|8/24/09|12/7/09|PLE|
|2|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Td|U049393AA|ASP|4/2/95|10/7/95|ODK|
|3|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Td|U049393AA|ASP|4/2/95|11/7/95|WMK|
|4|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Td|U049393AA|ASP|4/2/95|4/7/96|CPK|
|5|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Tdap|AC9349239AA|GSK|2/12/07|3/1/07|CPK|
|6|Measles, Mumps, Rubella|MMR|02302L|DVX|9/7/15|11/4/15|WNK|
|7|Hepatitis B|Heplisav-B|TD02302|DVX|9/9/16|10/4/18|WNK|
"""

vaccination_records = []
lines = vaccinations_text.strip().split('\n')
headers = lines[0].split('|')[1:-1]  
date_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2})')

for line in lines[1:]:
    values = line.split('|')[1:-1]  
    record = []

    for header, value in zip(headers, values):
        if header == 'Date given':
            date = date_pattern.search(value)
            if date:
                date = dt.datetime.strptime(date.group(0), '%m/%d/%y').date()
                record.append((header, date))
        else:
            record.append((header, value))

    vaccination_records.append(record)

print(vaccination_records)
```

As a bonus, here is code with the exact same result, using only standard Python libraries, in a few lines:

```
from csv import reader
from datetime import datetime

vaccinations_text = """
|Entry #|Vaccine|Type of vaccine|Lot #|Manufacturer|VIS edition date|Date given|Vaccinator (initials)|
|1|Influenza|H1N1|2F03930|NOV|8/24/09|12/7/09|PLE|
|2|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Td|U049393AA|ASP|4/2/95|10/7/95|ODK|
|3|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Td|U049393AA|ASP|4/2/95|11/7/95|WMK|
|4|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Td|U049393AA|ASP|4/2/95|4/7/96|CPK|
|5|Tetanus, Diphtheria, Pertussis|Tdap|AC9349239AA|GSK|2/12/07|3/1/07|CPK|
|6|Measles, Mumps, Rubella|MMR|02302L|DVX|9/7/15|11/4/15|WNK|
|7|Hepatitis B|Heplisav-B|TD02302|DVX|9/9/16|10/4/18|WNK|
"""

data = list(reader(vaccinations_text.strip().splitlines(), delimiter='|'))
vaccination_records = [
    list(zip(data[0][1:-1], [*line[1:7], datetime.strptime(line[7], '%m/%d/%y'), *line[8:-1]]))
    for line in data[1:]
]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your step by step explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `csv` module to extract the values:

```py
import csv
import datetime
from io import StringIO

sniffer = csv.Sniffer()  # Automatically detect dialect of your input data 
dlct    = sniffer.sniff(vaccinations_text, delimiters="|") 

data_io = StringIO(vaccinations_text.strip()) # convert your string to a file-like, 
                                              # or use this space to open a file handler 
                                              # (This one removed the leading newline for the benifit of the DictReader's first line field names)

reader  = csv.DictReader(data_io, dialect=dlct)  # Set up the csv DictReader
vaccination_records = [rec for rec in reader]    # extract the records (dictionaries) into a list
vaccination_records_dates = [{ k: datetime.datetime.strptime(v, '%m/%d/%y').date() if k in ["VIS edition date", "Date given",] else v for (k,v) in rec.items()} for rec in vaccination_records ]

# If you must have a list of tuples (also removed blank values):
vaccination_records_lot = [[x for x in rec.items() if x[0] != ''] for rec in vaccination_records_dates]
```

It's always a better idea to use the "batteries included" rather than rolling your own, if you can. After all: `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`